# Почему конструкторы с одним аргументом по умолчанию не сделаны explicit?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор, стандарт

Почему конструкторы с одним аргументом по умолчанию не сделаны explicit?

Comment: А почему они вдруг должны быть "explicit" по умолчанию? Невозможно осмысленно ответить на вопрос, не понимая основы его возникновения.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот и Страуструп в какой-то книге жалел об этом :) Но...

Знаете эту хохму - что диаметр баков космического корабля определяется размером лошадиного крупа в древнем Риме? Конечно, [байка](http://www.orator.ru/pr_56.html), но...

Так и тут - первоначальное решение, когда `explicit` не было и в помине, и резкий поворот "все вдруг" приведет к нарушению обратной совместимости и неработоспособности большого количества уже написанного кода.

Comment: Но можно же изменить это в новом стандарте, например, пометив как устаревшее

Comment: Это тот случай, когда переход *постепенно* невозможен. Как с `auto`, только им не пользовались :) Можно отменить `explicit` и ввести `implicit`, но поменять на противоположный смысл обычный код, где не используется *ничего*?... Да и вопрос уж точно не ко  мне, я ни в какой комитет по стандартизации не вхожу. А тут... Остается только развести руками и сказать "Ну, уж если сам Страуструп ничего не смог..." :)

Comment: @Harry,  наверное я чего то недопонел, но как бы для случаев  template < class B,  class T >  void f()  {  B b(arg); b = T(); }   и не нужно этого сделать... Что скажете?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Теперь уже недопонял я. Я хочу сказать, что есть масса кода, которая полагается на неявное преобразование типов из-за наличия соответствующих конструкторов, и если изменить поведение таких конструкторов - так, что эти преобразования более не будут допустимы - придется переделывать массу кода... Представьте на секунду, что будет, если, например, сделать `override` обязательным? :)

Comment: @Harry, зато теперь я понел, спасибо за ответ. Старею, ничего не поделаешь....